# C#: Deflating XML gives different result than doing it in JavaScript

Tags: c#, node.js, zip, saml-2.0

I am trying to deflate a xml in C# and encode it base64. I tried to use both DeflateStream and GZipStream but I seem to get a different result than doing it in a node library.
I will post the node code and the c# code:

```
//zlib = require('zlib');
zlib.deflateRaw(xml, (function(_this) {
      return function(err, deflated) {
             return deflated.toString('base64');
      }
}
```

C# DeflateStream

```
 private static byte[] Deflate(String str)
    {
      using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
      {
        using (DeflateStream gzip =
          new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
          using (StreamWriter writer =
            new StreamWriter(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
          {
            writer.Write(str);
          }
        }

        return output.ToArray();
      }
    }
```

C# GZipStream

```
public static byte[] Zip(string str)
{
      var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

      using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
      using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
      {
        using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
          //msi.CopyTo(gs);
          CopyTo(msi, gs);
        }

        return mso.ToArray();
      }
 }
```

C# Base64 Encode:

```
private static string Base64Encode(byte[] textBytes)
{
   return System.Convert.ToBase64String(textBytes);
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

**UPDATE**

I found an example that works. By using this I can also decode it using Node.

```
 var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToDeflate);
  using (var output = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var zip = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
      zip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());
  }
```

**UPDATE 2 (working code - for future searchers)**

```
private static string DeflateAndEncode(string str)
    {
      var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
      using (var output = new MemoryStream())
      {
        using (var zip = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
          zip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());

        return base64;
      }
    }

    private static string DecodeAndInflate(string str)
    {
      var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
      var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
      using (var output = new MemoryStream())
      {
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
          using (var unzip = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
          {
            unzip.CopyTo(output, bytes.Length);
            unzip.Close();
          }
          return utf8.GetString(output.ToArray());
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's an encoding issue. Could you try `new StreamWriter(gzip)` instead of UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @bommelding 513 characters in the Node output and 537 in the C# implementation

Comment: Added an update that seems to work.

Comment: @bommelding one difference that I spot (but I am not sure if it makes a difference) is not the working one doesn't use a StreamWriter.

Comment: public static void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest)
    {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

      int cnt;

      while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
      {
        dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

The characters used for base-64 encoding differ between C# and Node.js.

[C# uses the following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero are the uppercase characters "A" to "Z", the lowercase characters "a" to "z", the numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/". The valueless character, "=", is used for trailing padding.

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) uses ["The "URL and Filename safe" Base 64 Alphabet"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) as specified in RFC4648, Section 5:

```
A-Z, a-z, 0-9, - (minus), _ (underscore)
Trailing padding uses '='
```

So what you are trying to do won't work.

You could probably fix it by replacing the `_` and `-` characters with `+` and `/` respectively to convert the C# encoding to Node.js, and vice-versa before base64-decoding the data.

Comment: But that does not account for a difference in length.

Comment: @Matthew Watson, should this change be done in the original text? Because otherwise I have a byte array after deflating.

Comment: Could you give examples what strings differ? I tried "testcode!!!/+_-" but got the expected (equal) result. Here is my [NodeJSFiddler](https://runkit.com/freggar/5b31f43ffddc560012d9c2f2) and my [C#.NET Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9flq8X).

Comment: @Freggar Your base64 input to your test code doesn't include the differing characters. Try using this as your binary data: `Enumerable.Range(0, 255).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray()`

Comment: Strange, I'm still getting the same result (I updated my fiddler links)

Comment: @Freggar Hmm, strange indeed - according to the specs that I linked, Node.js uses the "_" character for base-64 encoding (and .Net doesn't use that character).